# Qt How to highlight menu?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, winapi

I need to do hide/show main menu function by pressing the Alt key (like in FireFox). I know how to hide and show it, but I can't highlight menu after showing it. I've tried `menuBar()->actions()[0].hover()`, `activateWindow()`, `setActiveAction()`, `activate(QAction::Hover)`, but nothing helps. How can I do it? Maybe I should use WinApi functions instead of Qt?

```
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *event){
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
    {
        QKeyEvent *ke = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
        if (ke->key() == Qt::Key_Alt)
        {
            keyReleaseEvent(ke);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return QMainWindow::event(event);
}
```

Handle Alt

```
void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent (QKeyEvent* event)
{
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Alt){
        if (menuBar()->isHidden()){
            menuBar()->show();
            menuBar()->setFocus(Qt::MenuBarFocusEvent); //here I trying to highlight the menu
        }
        else{
            menuBar()->hide();
        {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [How to focus menuBar() with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928937/how-to-focus-menubar-with-qt#answer-49341196) (which I just answered)

Because the answer isn't accepted on the other question, I can't flag this one as a duplicate. Including answer below as well:

---

I wanted to do the same thing. My solution, complete example, as a gist:

https://gist.github.com/xim/ee56564f425151ea2fa70f730d644873

As it contains a lot of other junk, a minimal example:

```
class AutoHidingMenuBar : public QMenuBar {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AutoHidingMenuBar() : QMenuBar() {
        setMaximumHeight(0);
        connect(qApp, &QApplication::focusChanged, this, &AutoHidingMenuBar::focusChanged);
    }

private slots:
    void focusChanged(QWidget *from, QWidget *to) {
        bool inFocus = hasFocus() || isAncestorOf(focus) || hasFocusedChild();
        if (inFocus && maximumHeight() == 0) {
            auto action = activeAction();
            setMaximumHeight(100);
            if (action) {
                // XXX This is a bit of a hack. We could do
                //   QCoreApplication::processEvents();
                //   setActiveAction(action);
                // with almost the same effect, but then we *open* the first menu on single alt press...
                auto evt = new QMouseEvent(QEvent::MouseMove, actionGeometry(action).center(), Qt::NoButton, Qt::NoButton, Qt::NoModifier);
                QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, evt);
            }
        } else if (!inFocus && maximumHeight() != 0)) {
            setMaximumHeight(0);
        }
    }

private:
    bool hasFocusedChild();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to debug it and see what is happening.

You can do something like:

```
if (menuBar()->hasFocus())
   qDebug() << " I have the focus";
else
  qDebug() << " I don't have the focus";
```

And see if it has the focus but works bad or if it has no focus which I think that is problem... somewhere it is losing it

A little trick that may help you is using:

```
 QTimer::singleShot(0, menuBar(), SLOT(setFocus()));
```

on your `MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent`

And last thing... Note that set focus needs a focusPolicy, maybe [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) helps you.

Comment: I've already tried this. It has focus, but it's not highlighted

Comment: I have  edited it, forgot about the focuspolicy, have you set it?

Comment: Tried `QTimer::singleShot(0, menuBar(), SLOT(setFocus()));` , it did not help

Comment: I know about focusPolicy, and already setted it to `Qt::StrongFocus`